# CSS clip-path + JS is glitchy on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, clip-path

I have an issue with my code. I'm trying to mask out the bottom of my main in a circular shape. Therefore, i used clip-path on it. Every thing is working smoothly on firefox, but on chrome when scrolling the page blinks. what have I done wrong ? By the way I am using, gsap and scroll magic on the page, I don't see how i could have an impact on it but ... ( no js + clip path works perfect, js whithout clip path works perfect, but together it bugs on chrome).

```
main{
    
    min-height:100vh;
    background:linear-gradient(to right top,#55c7d8 ,#b5ecf4 );
    overflow-x:hidden;
    clip-path: circle(3000px at 50% -50%);

}
```

my js file :

```
const parallax = document.getElementById("presentation");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    let offset = window.pageYOffset;
    parallax.style.marginTop= offset* 0.3 + "px";
})




jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll-down").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 1500);
    });
});

const cheminnageur = {
    curviness: 1.25,
    autoRotate: true,
    values: [{x: -40, y: 30},{x: -60, y: 55},{x: -40, y: 110},{x: 10, y: 120},{x: 50, y: 110},{x: 60, y: 80},{x: 40, y: 70},{x: 10, y: 70},{x: -30, y: 90},{x: -20, y: 130}]
};



const tween = new TimelineLite();

tween.add(
    TweenLite.to('.swimmer', 1,{
        bezier: cheminnageur,
        ease: Power1.ease
    })
);

const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: "#presentation",
    duration: 200,
    triggerHook: 0
})
.setTween(tween)
.addTo(controller);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=611257

Try to use `will-change` css property.